# Sub division rings of division rings

Tags: quaternions, division-algebras

Below $^\ast$ denotes "nonzero elements of".

There is a problem in Jacobson's Basic Algebra 1, there is a problem to this effect: if $S$ is a subdivision ring of $\mathbb{H}$ such that $S^\ast$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{H}^\ast$, then $S=\mathbb{H}$ or $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

The solution that came to mind relies a bit on $\mathbb{H}$ having a norm into $\mathbb{R}$, and probably the behavior of $i,j$ and $k$.

I couldn't see a proof for general division rings, though. Does anyone know if it's true for division rings, or have a counterexample?

My gut tells me to lean toward the latter, but I have been bitterly disappointed by my gut feelings before...

---

**Update:** Two things have happened: Rankeya has given a valid answer to the written question, but I realize now I was too vague. Secondly, I looked up the correct exercise in Jacobson and found that the following exercise is *precisely* to show that it does hold for all division rings. Stupid gut feelings...

I'm accepting this answer and reposting the correct question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: Take the function fields $\mathbb{R}(x)$ and $\mathbb{R}(x,y)$. Since they are fields, in particular they are division rings. The former is a subfield of the latter.  That  $\mathbb{R}(x)^*$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{R}(x,y)^*$ follows from commutativity of multiplication. But, $\mathbb{R}(x) \neq \mathbb{R}(x,y)$ and $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In my answer I exploited the fact that presumably in your general statement, you still want $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. But, may be this is not the generalization you are thinking of. Certainly having the ring $\mathbb{R}$ in a general version (whatever that version is) seems specialized.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you've addressed this question, but I've horribly misstated the question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a celebrated theorem due to Brauer-Cartan-Hua )independently) that asserts that: If D is a division ring with center F, then every subdivision ring H which H* is normal in D* is either central or the whole division ring D.

Your question is an special case of this theorem.

[The proof](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-06/S0002-9904-1949-09264-9/S0002-9904-1949-09264-9.pdf) of Cartan-Brauer-Hua theorem by Richard Brauer.

Answer (score 3):

**Cartan-Brauer-Hua Theorem:** Let $D$ be a division ring and $S$ be a division subring of $D$. If $S$ is stabilized by every map $x\mapsto dxd^{-1},d\in D^*$, this is, $\{dxd^{-1}|d\in D^*\}\subset S$ for every $x\in S$, then either $S=D$ or $S\subset C(D)$.

**Proof by Loo-Keng Hua:**

Hint: If $ab\ne ba$ then $a=[b^{-1}-(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1)][a^{-1}b^{-1}a-(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1)]^{-1}$.

Proof of Hint: If $ab\ne ba$ then $a,b\ne 0,1$.
$$b^{-1}a-b^{-1}=b^{-1}(a-1)=(a-1)(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1)$$
$$=a(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1)-(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1).$$

Then $$b^{-1}a-a(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1)=b^{-1}-(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1),$$
$$a[a^{-1}b^{-1}a-(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1)]=b^{-1}-(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1).$$

Since $ab\ne ba$, we have $(a-1)b\ne b(a-1)$ and $b^{-1}-(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1)\ne 0$. Hence $$a=[b^{-1}-(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1)][a^{-1}b^{-1}a-(a-1)^{-1}b^{-1}(a-1)]^{-1}.$$

Proof: If there exists an element $s\in S$ such that $ds\ne sd$, then $d\in S$ by the Hint. Hence for any $s\in S$ and any $d\in D-S$, $sd=ds$.

Suppose that $S$ is not contained in $C(D)$. There exist $s_1,s_2\in S$ such that $s_1s_1\ne s_1s_2$.

If $S\ne D$, there is an element $a\in D-S$. Since $as_1$ also belongs to $D-S$, we have $(as_1)s_2=s_2(as_1)$ $=(s_2a)s_1=(as_2)s_1$, which contradicts $s_1s_1\ne s_1s_2$.

Hence $S=D$.

[The link to the proof by Loo-Keng Hua.](http://www.pnas.org/content/35/9/533.full.pdf)

**Proof by Richard Brauer:**

If $d\in D, s\in S$, there exist $s_1,s_2\in S$ such that $$ds=s_1d,$$ $$(d+1)s=s_2(d+1).$$

Then $(d+1)s-ds=s_2(d+1)-s_1d$, this is, $$s-s_2=(s_2-s_1)d.$$

If $s_2-s_1\ne 0$ then $d\in S$. Therefore, if $d\not\in S$, then $s_2=s_1$ and $s=s_2$. Thus $s=s_1$, this is, $ds=sd$. Hence for any $s\in S$ and any $d\in D-S$, $sd=ds$.

Suppose that $S$ is not contained in $C(D)$. There exist $s_1,s_2\in S$ such that $s_1s_1\ne s_1s_2$.

If $S\ne D$, there is an element $a\in D-S$ and $as_2=s_2a$. Since $a+s_1$ also belongs to $D-S$, we have $(a+s_1)s_2=s_2(a+s_1)$, which contradicts $s_1s_1\ne s_1s_2$.

Hence $S=D$.

[The link to the proof by Richard Brauer.](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-06/S0002-9904-1949-09264-9/S0002-9904-1949-09264-9.pdf)